# Turn a table row in a css grid layout independent from other rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I've to rearrange a table like this one using only CSS.

```html
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; }
th, td {padding: 5px;}
th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>H1</th>
 <th>H2</th>
 <th>H3</th>
        <th>H4</th>
 <th>H5</th>
 <th>H6</th>
 <th>H7</th>
 <th>H8</th>
 <th>H9</th>
 <th>H10</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
 <td class="col-A1">A1</td>
        <td class="col-A2">A2</td>
 <td class="col-A3">A3</td>
 <td class="col-A4">A4</td>
 <td class="col-A5">A5</td>
 <td class="col-A6">A6</td>
 <td class="col-A7">A7</td>
 <td class="col-A8">A8</td>
 <td class="col-A9">A9</td>
 <td class="col-A10">A10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
 <td class="col-B1">B1</td>
 <td class="col-B2">B2</td>
 <td class="col-B3">B3</td>
 <td class="col-B4">B4</td>
        <td class="col-B5">B5</td>
 <td class="col-B6">B6</td>
 <td class="col-B7">B7</td>
 <td class="col-B8">B8</td>
 <td class="col-B9">B9</td>
 <td class="col-B10">B10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

How can I get a layout like this?
My initial idea would have been using CSS flexbox but I didn't know how to rearrange the row into this layout, especially the A2 to A7 part in which there are two columns.

So as suggested by comments to original post, I would opt for a CSS grid layout.

[image: Table final layout]

Comment: Are you allowed to change the HTML structure at all?

Comment: No, I'm not, only CSS.

Comment: This would be a good candidate for CSS Grid, but it would definitely require some HTML changes to make nested grids.  I'm not saying it's not possible, but I can't think of a flexbox solution that wouldn't require more containers for the "A" section.  Why can't you edit the HTML? Is it an assignment?  If so it's a tough one.  I suppose you could absolutely position each individual cell

Comment: I agree with @RutherfordWonkington, Its an ideal grid layout. Without the absolute positioning, getting this layout on `table` is not a way forward.

Comment: This is not possible with css tables even if you rearrange the rows because `col-A9` and `col-A10` occupy 2.5 columns each.... with flexbox you would find difficulty *spanning the rows* (eg `col-A2`) and can be solved only if you nest more container.... but with **css grids** this is actually easy...

Comment: https://cssgrid-generator.netlify.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with *tables* even if you rearrange the rows because `col-A9` and `col-A10` occupy 2.5 columns each. And with *flexbox* you would find difficulty spanning the rows (eg `col-A2`) and can be solved only if you nest more containers.

But with css grids this is actually easy - you can use a 20-column layout here. See demo with explanations inline:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid; /* establish a grid container */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 1fr); /* 20 columns */
  grid-auto-rows: 50px; /* row height for illustration */
}

.wrapper div {
  border: 1px solid;
  grid-column: span 2; /* span two columns */ 
  /* flexbox to center content*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper .a {
  grid-column: span 10;  /* span ten columns */ 
}

.wrapper .a1 {
  grid-column: span 20; /* span all 20 columns */ 
}

.wrapper .a2 {
  grid-row: span 5; /* span five rows */ 
}

.wrapper .a9,.wrapper .a10{
  grid-column: span 5; /* span five columns */ 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="h">H1</div>
  <div class="h">H2</div>
  <div class="h">H3</div>
  <div class="h">H4</div>
  <div class="h">H5</div>
  <div class="h">H6</div>
  <div class="h">H7</div>
  <div class="h">H8</div>
  <div class="h">H9</div>
  <div class="h">H10</div>
  
  <div class="a a1">A1</div>
  <div class="a a2">A2</div>
  <div class="a a3">A3</div>
  <div class="a a4">A4</div>
  <div class="a a5">A5</div>
  <div class="a a6">A6</div>
  <div class="a a7">A7</div>
  <div class="a a8">A8</div>
  <div class="a a9">A9</div>
  <div class="a a10">A10</div>
  
  <div class="b">B1</div>
  <div class="b">B2</div>
  <div class="b">B3</div>
  <div class="b">B4</div>
  <div class="b">B5</div>
  <div class="b">B6</div>
  <div class="b">B7</div>
  <div class="b">B8</div>
  <div class="b">B9</div>
  <div class="b">B10</div>
  
</div>
```